# Getting compile error on type parameter with multiple bounds

Tags: java, generics

Why am I getting this compiler error on *FuzzyWuzzyContainer*?

> Bound mismatch:The type FuzzyWuzzy is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter `<T extends Fuzzy & Comparable<T>>` of the type
>   FuzzyContainer

*FuzzyWuzzy* does in fact implement both interfaces that are defined in the bounded generic.

```
public interface Fuzzy
{
    boolean isFuzzy();
}

public class FuzzyWuzzy implements Fuzzy, Comparable<Fuzzy>
{
    public boolean isFuzzy() {return true;}
    public int compare(Fuzzy o) {return 0;)
}

public abstract class FuzzyContainer<T extends Fuzzy & Comparable<T>>
{
   :
}

public class FuzzyWuzzyContainer extends Fuzzycontainer<FuzzyWuzzy> // Error is here
{
}
```

Comment: Do you want `FuzzyWuzzy implements Fuzzy, Comparable<FuzzyWuzzy>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring `FuzzyContainer` like this:

```
public abstract class FuzzyContainer<T extends Fuzzy & Comparable<? super T>>
```

This is necessary since `FuzzyWuzzy` implements `Comparable<Fuzzy>` rather than `Comparable<FuzzyWuzzy>` (you could also make that change, as [The Cat pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401620/697449)).

Comment: Thank you.  I have a keyboard imprint on my forehead from trying to figure this out yesterday that can now wear off  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `FuzzyWuzzy implements Comparable<Fuzzy>`. The `FuzzyContainer` is expecting both `T`s in `FuzzyContainer<T extends Fuzzy & Comparable<T>>` to be the same type. `FuzzyWuzzy` implements `Fuzzy` but it doesn't implement `Comparable<FuzzyWuzzy>`.

Try, `FuzzyWuzzy implements Fuzzy, Comparable<FuzzyWuzzy>`

Comment: Good answer, unfortunately not the right one for my particular use case.